# Project Clarity - Fixed Navigation

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm trying to create a fixed Navbar using  [Project Clarity](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/)

I'm using it in my Angular project, they are using FlexBox, I have tried putting in `position: fixed` but it doesn't seem to work, anyone have any ideas ?

```
<clr-header class="header-6">
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, can you share all of your html? Or, even better, fork this StackBlitz add your code there and share that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v11

Comment: Hi there!  sorry I haven't responded sooner, I can link you directly to my github page for the navbar component if that is better ? =]  Click [here](https://github.com/patangney/fourthyear/blob/master/src/app/shared/navbar/navbar.component.html "github")!  Its nothing special just a project Im doing in college, just so used to using bootstrap and came across Project Clarity and just thought Id try out something different =] What Im trying to achieve is to keep the header fixed on scroll, I think bootstrap are using ' fixed-top ' perhaps this has changed in the new version

Comment: I added an answer that I hope clears up the Application layout for a Clarity App with an example of a large amount of content that scroll under the app header. @Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix the header so that content scrolls underneath it, your application needs to have the correct [Application Layout](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/app-layout). Our components work within this structure because `A properly structured layout enforces an optimal, consistent experience across applications.`

The general structure for A Clarity Application layout takes this form:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="alert alert-app-level">
        ...
    </div>
    <header class="header header-6">
        ...
    </header>
    <nav class="subnav">
        ...
     </nav>
     <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content-area">
            ...
         </div>
        <nav class="sidenav">
            ...
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, you can get rid of the parts that may not be relevant to your app like: `alert-app-level`, `subnav` etc ...

You can see this working in a [quick demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-aapp-layout) I made with inspiration from [Bob Ross](http://www.bobrosslipsum.com/). As you can see the content scroll underneath the application header.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to respond!  I didn't even notice the main-container and or content-container, I should pay more attention to the docs!  Thanks for your help with this! =]

Comment: hi hippeelee. I have exactly the same problem although i have 100% the same structure as your html & css. Actually i built every part of this main html as an individual Angular component, so actually there are some host-element tags between those tags.. may this make a problem?

Comment: Yes. That might cause the css to fail.

Comment: sorry but the css is very poorly designed then, since it is clearly not selecting things with class definitions but with a very strict html structure. it is also funny that the  library has an angular cooperation and has some predefined angular components, still the whole clarity css ignores the angular's component structure. For instance, at very this moment, I wanted to define clr-header in its own component without creating an additional host-element-tag (since the clarity css does not work then). But this way does not work either: "more than one component matched". Angular error.

Comment: I would love to help you. Please ask a new question and provide a stackblitz that replicates the issue you are seeing. Then tag the question with vmware-clarity soni get notified. It’s very difficult to say what the problem is without seeing working code that I can debug with dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

if someone has also either very this problem, or another problem where some css does not work within Angular:

Since we mostly structure our UI code in multiple components in Angular, and since each component puts its own host-tag in the generated DOM between the actual html tags, the clarity library has some problems with it.

So as a workaround, if you still want to be able to keep your current htmls as they are, you can define this css in each your component's css file:

```
:host { display: contents; }
```

This causes the component's box not to render; means the host tags are still visible in DOM, but they will not have any effect regarding CSS. And any clarity CSS will work again.